# Separate command-line arguments into two lists and pass to programs (shell)

Tags: sh

What I want to do is take a list of command-like arguments like `abc "def ghi" "foo bar" baz` (note that some arguments are quoted because they contain spaces), and separate them out into two lists of arguments which then get passed to other programs that are invoked by the script. For example, odd-numbered arguments to one program and even-numbered arguments to another program. It is important to preserve proper quoting.

Please note, I need a solution in pure Bourne Shell script (i.e., `sh` not `bash` or such). The way I'd do this in Bash would be to use arrays, but of course the Bourne Shell doesn't have support for arrays.

Comment: `sh`, in modern usage, refers to a shell that conforms to  the POSIX shell specification, not the Bourne shell.

Comment: @chepner Fair enough, but the name of the executable for the Bourne shell was `sh` too. :-)

Comment: Ah, I just saw you were referring to @ghoti's edit... oh well. I'm not too bothered either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the cost of iterating over the original arguments twice, you can define a function that can run a *simple* command using only the even or odd arguments. This allows us to use the function's arguments as an additional array.

```
# Usage:
#  run_it <cmd> [even|odd] ...
# 
#  Runs <cmd> using only the even or odd arguments, as specified.
run_it () {
    cmd=${1:?Missing command name}
    parity=${2:?Missing parity}
    shift 2

    n=$#

    # Collect the odd arguments by discarding the first
    # one, turning the odd arguments into the even arguments.
    if [ $# -ge 1 ] && [ $parity = odd ]; then
        shift
        n=$((n - 1))
    fi

    # Repeatedly move the first argument to the
    # to the end of the list and discard the second argument.
    # Keep going until you have moved or discarded each argument.
    while [ "$n" -gt 0 ]; do
        x=$1
        if [ $n -ge 2 ]; then
            shift 2
        else
            shift
        fi
        set -- "$@" "$x"
        n=$((n-2))
    done

    # Run the given command with the arguments that are left.
    "$cmd" "$@"
}

# Example command
cmd () {
    printf '%s\n' "$@"
}

# Example of using run_it
run_it cmd even "$@"
run_it cmd odd "$@"
```

Comment: Good call, thank you! I think this probably the only way to do it and preserve quoting.

Comment: Would echoing `"$@"` from the `run_it` fn then `eval`ing that along with the command (program name) work?

Comment: The problem with `eval` is that values from any parameter expansions become syntax to be parsed by `eval`, so you have to preemptively escape it. That's what the `%q` specifier in `bash`'s built-in `printf` does for you, but POSIX doesn't have anything equivalent.

Comment: Aha, I see. So this looks like the only proper solution then. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you need. Alas, it uses eval. YMMV.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Samples
foo() { showme foo "$@"; }
bar() { showme bar "$@"; }
showme() {
        echo "$1 args:"
        shift
        local c=0
        while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
                printf '\t%-3d %s\n' $((c=c+1)) "$1"
                shift
        done
}

while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
        foo="$foo \"$1\""
        bar="$bar \"$2\""
        shift 2
done

eval foo $foo
eval bar $bar
```

There's no magic here -- we simply encode alternating arguments with quote armour into variables so they'll be processed correctly when you `eval` the line.

I tested this with FreeBSD's /bin/sh, which is based on ash. The shell is close to POSIX.1 but is not necessarily "Bourne". If your shell doesn't accept arguments to `shift`, you can simply shift twice in the while loop. Similarly, the `showme()` function increments a counter, an action which can be achieved in whatever way is your favourite if mine doesn't work for you. I believe everything else is pretty standard.

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a go later. `eval` isn't ideal, but it's certainly nice that there's a POSIX solution. Would you mind explaining `printf '\t%-3d %s\n' $((c=c+1)) "$1"`? I'm not sure why the integer argument is needed, specifically.

Comment: @Noldorin .. My pleasure. The integer argument isn't *needed* per-se, I only included that to provide some kind of useful output from the `showme()` function. One could achieve the same thing by piping the loop through `nl`. As I said, use your favourite method if you need a shell counter. :-)

Comment: This fails if an argument contains a double quote, e.g. `./tmp.sh abc "def \"ghi" "foo bar" baz`.

Comment: @chepner, it does indeed, hence the "might" in the first sentence and the early disclosure of eval. Do you have a solution?